# getSheetByName not finding the sheet even though it exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I am driving myself crazy with this. Basically I am trying to write a script that copies a spreadsheet template and a form template, creates a tab for the form responses in the new copy of the spreadsheet template, and then renames the form responses tab. It was working perfectly until I made some small ***unrelated*** adjustment without saving the old version and now when I try to retrieve the "Form Responses 1" tab, it returns null every time, even though there is definitely a tab called "Form Responses 1".

Here is the code basically:

```
var sheetTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0123456789');
var sheetCopy = sheetTemplate.copy('Spreadsheet name');
var sheetCopyId = sheetCopy.getId();

var formTemplateId = '987654321';
var formFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('123123123');
var formName = 'Form name'
var formCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(formTemplateId).makeCopy(formName, formFolder);

form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, sheetCopyId);

var formResponsesSheet = sheetCopy.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
formResponsesSheet.setName('New sheet name'); // this is where it errors out
```

And this is the error I get: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setName')`

Please help I am going nuts

Comment: For example, as the confirmation of the sheet names, when you run the script of `console.log(JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.openById('0123456789').getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName())))`, can you confirm the sheet name of `Form Responses 1` in the log?

Comment: Almost always,  it's a typo in the sheet name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I fixed this issue by adding in `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before referencing the tab. Hope this helps someone!